# How to solve this differential equation corresponding to the RL circuit?

Tags: rectifier

> [image]
>
> When VT is under on-state, this function is set up:
>
> $$L\frac{di_d}{dt} + Ri_d = \sqrt{2}U_2\sin(\omega t) \quad\quad\quad\quad (1-1)$$

I can't solve this function :(

> The instantaneous moment when VT was into on-state, $$\omega t = \alpha$$ $$i_d = 0$$ this is the **Initial condition** of the function above.
>   Solving the function and substitude initial condition into the solution, we got:
>
> $$i_d = -\frac{\sqrt{2}U_2}{Z}\sin(\alpha - \varphi)e^{-\frac{R}{\omega L}(\omega t-\alpha)}+\frac{\sqrt{2}U_2}{Z}\sin(\omega t-\varphi) \quad\quad (1-2)$$
>
> where
>   $$Z = \sqrt{R^2+(\omega L)^2}$$
>
> $$\varphi = \arctan(\frac{\omega L}{R})$$

I tried to solve (1-1) and get (1-2) but got into a mess:

$$L\frac{di_d}{dt} = \sqrt{2} U_2 \sin(\omega t) - Ri_d$$

$$\frac{di_d}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{2} U_2 \sin(\omega t) - Ri_d}{L}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} U_2 \sin(\omega t) - Ri_d}di_d = \frac{1}{L}dt$$

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} U_2 \sin(\omega t) - Ri_d}di_d = \int\frac{1}{L}dt$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}\ln(i_d)}{2R\cdot U_2 \sin(\omega t)}+C_1 = \frac{t}{L}+C_2$$

And I got stuck... ㅠㅠ

Comment: You can solve this using Laplace transform.

Comment: Check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L\frac{di_d}{dt} = \sqrt{2} U_2 \sin(\omega t) - Ri_d$$
$$\frac{di_d}{dt} + \frac{R}{L}i_d = \frac{\sqrt{2} U_2}{L} \sin(\omega t)$$
Multiplying both sides by e^(Rt/L),
$$e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\frac{di_d}{dt} + e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\frac{R}{L}i_d = e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\frac{\sqrt{2} U_2}{L} \sin(\omega t)$$
By product rule of differentiation,
 $$\frac{d(e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}i_d)}{dt} = e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\frac{\sqrt{2} U_2}{L} \sin(\omega t)$$
$$e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}i_d = \int e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\frac{\sqrt{2} U_2}{L} \sin(\omega t) dt$$
$$i_d = e^{\frac{-Rt}{L}}\int e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\frac{\sqrt{2} U_2}{L} \sin(\omega t) dt$$

Integrating and substituting your initial conditions, you should get your solution for i.

Comment: I solved the your equation by using SymPy, I got this:
$$e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}i_d = 
\frac{\sqrt{2}U_2(-\frac{L^2\omega \cdot e^{\frac{Rt}{L}} \cos(\omega t)}{L^2\omega^2 + R^2} + \frac{LR\cdot e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\sin(\omega t)}{L^2\omega^2 + R^2})}{L}$$
it's closer to the answer
$$i_d = -\frac{\sqrt{2}U_2}{Z}\sin(\alpha - \varphi)e^{-\frac{R}{\omega L}(\omega t-\alpha)}+\frac{\sqrt{2}U_2}{Z}\sin(\omega t-\varphi)$$
than the mess I made, But I still stuck here, sorry my math is terrible ㅠ.ㅠ

Comment: I rewrite it in this form, 
$$i_d\cdot e^{\frac{Rt}{L}} = -\frac{\sqrt{2}U_2}{Z^2}\cos(\alpha)\cdot L\omega \cdot e^{\frac{Rt}{L}} + \frac{\sqrt{2}U_2}{Z^2}\sin(\alpha)\cdot R \cdot e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}$$
but I don't know what's the next step?

Comment: Sorry I got two questions: 

**1.** I don't understand why did you multiplied
$$e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}$$
in 
$$(2-1)$$
**2.** In 
$$(2-2)$$
Why 
$$e^{\frac{Rt}{L}}\frac{R}{L}i_d$$
just been eliminated without reason?
@Kevin Selva Prasanna

Comment: This is the standard procedure for solving linear differential equations. Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> $$L\frac{di_d}{dt} = \sqrt{2} U_2 \sin(\omega t) - Ri_d $$

Its a transcendental equation whose closed form solution does not exist. You can also try to plug random values of i<sub>d</sub>, but that's stupidity.

Google Newton Raphson method which can help to approximate the solution.

Edit: Its a first order linear differential equation as pointed by @Kevin Selva Prasanna

Comment: You can solve it using Laplace transform.

Comment: It is a standard first order linear differential equation. A solution should exist. I don't think the equation is transcendental.

Comment: Yes my bad its solution does exist. Lazy morning.